# Trying to install deezer's AI "spleeter"

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

so I've been trying to install spleeter since yesterday. I've downloaded anaconda, created an environment I called "splter" (because it won't let me name it as the AI itself) and I've followed the instructions given on github, but I keep having this error:

```
(splter) C:\Users\User>conda install -c conda-forge spleeter
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
```

`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`

`Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`

`Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done`
`Solving environment: done`

`## Package Plan ##`

`environment location: C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\splter`

`added / updated specs:
-spleeter`

`The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:`

```
## then the names of all packages ##

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

`(splter) C:\Users\User>spleeter separate -h # to get help on the command's option`

``` Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ``'"d:\bld\spleeter_1574775894867\_h_env\python.exe" ```  `"C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\splter\Scripts\spleeter.exe" separate -h'`

Could I get some help?

Comment: i have the same issue today on Win10 and cant found a solution

Answer (score 1):

Try with below command

python -m spleeter separate -i "filename" -p spleeter:2stems -o temp